# How can vegans alleviate the effects of spicy food?

Tags: vegan, spicy-hot

It's well-known that if you eat spicy food, you can neutralize the flavor (and thus stop your mouth from burning like a forest fire) by drinking milk.  This is due to casein. Simply drinking water or something cold does not achieve the same effect.

But I'm vegan, so I don't drink milk. **So what else can I consume (that's vegan) to quickly neutralize spicy flavors?**

This is not a duplicate of [How can I wash down spicy food?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4403/how-can-i-wash-down-spicy-food), as the advice there concentrates on dairy products.

Comment: Hi JesseTG, I know why you thought this might run afoul of the "what to put in my dish" rule. In general, we don't take "what to put in my mouth" questions either, because they are based on taste. But I think this one makes a good exception. Cleaned up the wording; the question is not in danger of being closed.

Comment: capsein is fat soluble which is the 'real' trick here. Water makes it worse since it dosen't actually bind with the chemicals

Comment: Why do you feel you need to do anything? Just enjoy the wonderful taste of the spice.

Comment: In asian countries (Thai) they use coconut flakes or salty peanuts to avoid the hot spicy flavour.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have done no testing of this at all but I was surprised to find [on this site](http://www.tablespoon.com/posts/so-you-have-a-hot-mouth/c2e47b7b-173f-4db5-8a1e-757c0c77c34a) that they recommend trying a spoon full (or cube of) sugar.

> Perhaps the easiest way of calming down a flaming mouth is by sucking on a sugar cube or holding a teaspoon of sugar in your mouth. This helps by absorbing the spicy oil that is coating your mouth, as well as giving you a different, strong taste to concentrate on. A bit of mind-trickery and science combined!

Other things I've eaten in the past include starches, like bread or rice.

Here's a fun infographic and most of the items on it are vegan:

[image: Infographic of foods you can eat to kill spicy flavor]
from [here](http://thesecretyumiverse.wonderhowto.com/how-to/9-ways-cool-down-your-burning-hot-mouth-after-eating-really-spicy-foods-0154031/)

Comment: Coconut milk works brilliantly IN food to balance spicyness, and does not have casein (apart from a few brands that add some!), so dairy products aren't just about the casein when it comes to that ability.

Comment: Peanut butter is certainly very effective.

Comment: Peanut (butter) is another example of something that often goes into food to balance spice (Panang Curry, Anything Ka Salan) ... and there is a common theme with the coconut milk: Easily emulsified, good tasting FAT.

Comment: Beer works great but I would avoid a really hoppy one like a IPA because that can add to the discomfort.  A good tripel or something sweet works great.  Of course you probably want to do some research on whether a given beer is vegan.  It's really the sugar in milk that counteracts the hotness.  The commonly used Scoville scale tells you how much spice is needed to overcome a standard concentration of sugar water.

Comment: FWIW, in my country is is not at all well known that drinking milk reduces heat from spicy foods. But it is well known, and perhaps has always been well known, that eating sugar helps a lot. Unlike milk, there is no scientific explanation for sugar. Just hundreds of years of experience passed down from grandmothers to their grandchildren. This is why a lot of south-east-asian savoury food contain sugar. Take for example the peanut sauce. Nobody here thinks that the peanut reduces the heat, instead everyone believes it's the sugar added to the sauce.

Comment: @Darkhogg this is localized by the way... in some countries sugar is considered vegan by most by default unless there is reason to assume it is imported, in some it isn't ... has to do with what processes the local sugar industry is known to use.

Comment: Sugar is the best counteraction to spice in recipes, both because sugar generates a pleasure response in the brain that overrides the sensation of discomfort from spicy foods *and* because it produces a mild cooling sensation as it dissolves on the tongue.

Comment: What I doubt is that acidic foods help - from experience, vinegar or lemon can make too-spicy food even more unpleasant....

Answer (score 15):

Avocado would be the classic answer IME (often in the form of guacamole, but not required to be in that form.) AFAIK it's the fat effectively diluting the hot pepper oil in either case, (where it's unaffected by water since it won't mix) rather than any enzyme.

...and then there's not making the food so spicy it's uncomfortable (horribly unfashionable, I know, but I care less and less about fashionable as time passes.)

Comment: Let's not have a discussion about whether spicy food is good here. The question is how to cool down if you overdo it, not why you eat spicy food.

Comment: 1. You might not be the one making the food, thus you are not in control of the exact level of spicyness. 2. Making food slightly uncomfortably spicy is how you get used to spicy food, and as someone who went from completely unable to eat spicy food to loving spicy food, let me tell you, it's definitely worth a few uncomfortably spicy meals to get to that point.

Comment: 4. You might be making the food, but the recipe or method calls for adding the chili very early in the process (applies to a lot of south-east asian cooking). The chili you use is either fresh produce subject to variation, or you might be using an unfamiliar brand of dried chili, or use it in a matter you are inexperienced with. There are reasons not to taste them straight. And interestingly, it seems the hotter you can eat, the less margin you have for error - 10 of given brand of chili in given dish, its almost on the mild side, 20 of them ... holy hashtag raincloud skull and crossbones!

Comment: "Avocado would be the classic answer" Well, it's certainly _a_ classic answer; suggesting that it's _the_ classic answer seems rather Mexican-centric.

Answer (score 11):

There's a great answer to this from Vietnam, where super-spicy food is popular and dairy generally isn't. It combines many of the other suggestions into something wonderfully smooth and soothing:

### **Avocado and coconut milk smoothie**

[Here's one example recipe and pic](http://appetiteforchina.com/recipes/vietnamese-avocado-shake-sinh-bo). Note that in Vietnam, they love (non-vegan) condensed milk and tend to add it to everything - just skip the condensed milk, and in its place add more coconut milk and a little more sugar.

[image]

It has everything you'd want to cool chillies: creamyness, crushed ice, liquid, fats, sugars, along with a very mild non-clashing flavour and lots of nutritional value.

I've seen various variants on this which are even more cooling and soothing by adding **aloe vera** or **blended cucumber** - or give it a slight kick with some **lemon juice**.

Comment: I want one of these regardless of whether I've eaten spicy food :O

Answer (score 9):

Try a nut milk (almond comes to mind), soy milk or coconut milk. [Here's a highly rated recipe](http://www.glutenfreeveganpantry.com/the-best-damn-vegan-sour-cream/) for vegan "Sour Cream".

Comment: I'd recommend coconut milk -- the reason that cow's milk works is a combination of fat (capsaicin is fat soluble) and sugar (which soothes your taste buds) -- and if I recall correctly, coconut milk is the fattiest of the bunch.  (and most nut milks are watered down, anyway)

Comment: Soy/coconut yoghurt might be a good choice too.

Comment: As a slight variation on nut milk: [horchata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horchata) is very good for this (at least the Spanish kind, *horchata de chufas*; I’m not sure about the Latin American variants, which are quite different in composition but I’m told fairly comparable in taste).

Comment: Almond milk! I think it tastes better than dairy milk anyway.

Answer (score 8):

I've always liked the bread solution more than the dairy solution. It somehow feels to me that bread "mops up" the spicy stuff from my mucosa, while dairy dissolves it, but also spreads it around in my mouth. Maybe it's just a matter of personal preference, but when you can't have dairy, and even when you can, bread is worth to try. Just a piece of fresh white wheat bread without anything on it, no butter etc. Fluffier is better.

I generally eat yeast bread, but if your dietary restrictions don't permit it, I think chemically leavened bread should work sufficiently well.

Answer (score 4):

Im surprised not to see raw cucumber here - I thought it was a standard go-to.  Sliced, or just munch on one raw, depending on how much of your mouth is on fire :-)

Answer (score 4):

Obvious answer is strong alcohol like vodka. It doesn't contain any animal products so I suppose vegan can use it.

Comment: _"Why are you drunk, it's 9 in the morning!" "Well, I had this really spicy burrito for breakfast..."_ Could work really well as a sort of mouthwash, though.

Comment: Alcohol can do the opposite, depending on circumstances - dissolve all the capsaicin around and deliver it straight to your mouth membranes. Vodka that had a bunch of Thai chilies in it is hard to drink. And unlike oil, alcohols are usually thin liquids that fasten rather than slow absorption... BTW, milk filtered vodka is not vegan :)

Answer (score 2):

I am an omnivore but even better than milk  I HIGHLY recommend a  starch to correct a mouth burn from capacasain. The ideal being Wonderbread type of bread.

If at a restaurant you should be able to be able to order 1 of these depending if its Asian (rice, add coconut), Latin American (flour tortillas, sweet potatoes, add avacado) African (injera), Euro or euro-american (pasta, bread, potato) or middle eastern, (couscous, lemon).

At home most people in English language countries have either bread or cooked rice.

Soft white sliced commercial bread (i.e. Wonderbread etc.) is ideal but even pita bread can work. Tear off crust, pop in mouth, can use additional slices to rub on lips etc if it's a child or very sensitive adult. Make sure child washes hands with lathery soap!

When I was 6 I opened a butter tub but it was being used as Tupperware and filled with jalapeno liquid w the peppers. I didn't eat it, but it got on my hands and I only washed it off with water. of course my hands got in my mouth eventually.
I thought I was dying as I had only been exposed to Irish-American cooking,  (mostly boiled veggies, meats, only spices like salt, peppercorn or paprika).
The wonder bread helped immensely.

Answer (score 1):

You could also eat spicy food more often, that way you'll get used to it and won't need to wash away the spice.

Your tolerance will get higher pretty quickly.

Comment: This works long-term, but not for the current mouthful. Also, even once you've built up a tolerance, there will be dishes that exceed your current level of comfort.

Comment: @Erica though for some of us, that's the point ;)

Comment: This is a totally legitimate thing to do, but it's not what I was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are preparing the spicy food yourself, the easiest way to mitigate the Capsaicin "burn" is the well tried Szechuan method of adding some sugar to the cooking.

If you are dining out, the way I have mitigated the "burn" after more than a decade living in South East Asia and Sri Lanka, is to eat a spoonful of plain steamed rice.  Rather than drinking anything which will just wash the Capsaicin further down your digestive tract, the rice will quickly absorb the enzyme in your mouth, thus reducing any further ill effects.

Both these methods will work for vegans and non-vegans.

Answer (score 1):

Tofu works amazingly well, especially fresh and cold from the fridge. I just tried it for the worst mouth on fire, and it worked immediately!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to take a small amount of coconut oil in your mouth and let it melt, then swish it around and swallow.  It should absorb the capsaicin oil and take it along out of your mouth.

Trader Joe's organic virgin coconut oil would be my particular recommendation; it has a well-rounded, sweet coconut flavor and good texture.  It's not explicitly marked as vegan as far as I can tell, but I'd think it would be fine.

[image: TJ Organic Virgin Coconut Oil]

Answer (score 0):

My Family are usually Water Drinkers at a restaurant since soft drinks are pricy. However, one time my Dad was eating out as part of a Business Luncheon and out of the blue he decided to order Cranberry Juice. A little while into the meal he had something spicy and when he took a drink of his Cranberry Juice, the spiciness seemed to leave.  I think he tried it again by eating the spicy food & then drinking Cranberry Juice right afterwards.

I think you could try having Cranberry Juice and luckily it's a popular enough drink that you won't have trouble finding it in your Grocery Store! :)
I've also seen online that sucking on a citrus fruit could help with this!

Answer (score -3):

You don't have to drink it for it to work; it just has to be in your mouth. Is that against the rules? I'm not vegan nor am I lactose intolerant, I also don't drink milk but I'll ask for a glass if this needs doing (and then spit it out).

Comment: It depends on the vegan; however, many will also not wear leather or use animal-based body products (e.g. goat's milk soap or lotion with lanolin), so using a mouthful of dairy milk in such a way that it can't be drunk by somebody else can also count as "consuming" it.

Comment: You're missing the point of veganism (at least as I see it).  If I were to buy dairy milk to do so in the first place, I'm giving a large corporation money to torture cows.

Comment: @Erica - Right, consume *or use* - I should've looked it up first. I thought it was they just don't *eat* X.

Comment: Vegans can be vegan for all sorts of reasons.  Some because of animal rights, some because of health reasons.  Still, even a vegan who was so for health reasons is unlikely to have dairy milk around the house, no?