# can ice help with spicy food?

Tags: freezing, spices, spicy-hot

This is more just out of curiosity then anything. I just wondered could eating ice or somehow making you mouth colder before eating spicy foods, such as chill peppers or such, help lessen the spiciness?

Comment: Maybe, but make sure you put the toilet paper in the fridge.

Answer (score 6):

No.

The chemical action of [capsaicin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsaicin) (the compound that triggers the burning sensation) is an effect on chemical receptors in your taste buds. It's perceived to a degree as temperature but it's entirely independent, so making your mouth colder wouldn't help.

The only way cold would minimize a spice burn is if you made your tongue/mouth cold enough to freeze, numb, and damage your taste buds, which would be a *really bad idea*.

Ice won't really help relieve the burn after you start feeling the spice either, because capsaicin isn't water-soluble. [Here are some better suggestions for relief](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/4405/25059).