# How do you remove cayenne pepper (capsicum oils) from your hands?

Tags: cleaning, chili-peppers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cure for burns from hot peppers / capsicum oil?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3903/cure-for-burns-from-hot-peppers-capsicum-oil)

The cayenne pepper crops are in and I have been stringing peppers for winter use and drying, I also tend to use a lot of peppers in my dishes but inevitably an hour after processing those peppers I will rub my eyes, and that is a lot of burn. I know I could use latex/rubber gloves but I am not going to. I have tried everything including dishwashing detergent, the dry kind, lava soap, vinegar, and coffee grounds nothing seems to work. How do you remove those oils from your hands?