# Burning from Pepper?

Tags: chili-peppers

I was wondering if anyone knew how to get rid of this burning sensation on my hands from some peppers that I chopped earlier this evening. I've washed my hands multiple times and it seems that I am unable to wash off the acid. Does anyone know of a technique to rid myself of this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3903/cure-for-burns-from-hot-peppers-capsicum-oil

Comment: (I'll just go ahead and put on hold as duplicate for now, since this is the kind of question that attracts answers pretty easily and we don't need them all duplicated.)

Comment: aaaand merged. If you did have a different question, you can just post it as a new question!